# RANK EQ and COUNTIF -1

Tags: excel-formula, countif, ranking-functions

I'm trying to breakdown a formula that a previous coworker had put in but cannot figure out why the -1 was inserted into this formula.

The sheet is intended to randomize numbers and assign it to an associate of our company.

This is the formula we're working with: =RANK.EQ(B6,B:B)+COUNTIF($B$2:B6,B6)-1

Comment: Looks like the formula does a ranking without duplicates. Try to evaluate the formula it will explain you all. From Formula Tab --> Evaluate

Comment: We use worksheets within Workday, so unable to view a formula tab to evaluate it

Comment: That `COUNTIF()` function is used to return rolling counts, like if there is a duplicate, instead of returning `2`,`2` it will return `1`,`2` etc. so the `RANK()` function is returning the rank of the values. adding the both returns a combined value, lastly subtracting with 1 ensures that counting starts with 1 ensuring without duplicates.

Comment: If you want to randomize, you might be better off using sort and rand array (if your Excel version has access to them)